# Trimming lines of input for a set in Rust

Tags: rust, borrowing

This Rust program collects words/lines from the user, and adds each to the variable `line_set`. I'd like to change the code to *trim* each word before adding it to `line_set`.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io;

fn main() {
  let mut line_set = HashSet::new();

  for i in 1..4 {
    let mut line = String::new();
    io::stdin()
      .read_line(&mut line)
      .expect("Failed to read line");
    //let line = line.trim();
    line_set.insert(line.clone());
    if i == 3 {
      for l in &line_set {
        println!("{}", l);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to add a call to `String::trim`, applied to the current word, the program no longer compiles:

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:20
   |
12 |         let line = line.trim();
   |                    ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 |         line_set.insert(line.clone());
   |         -------- borrow later used here
...
19 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I used `rustc`'s `--explain` switch, and it relates that "This error occurs because a value was dropped while it was still borrowed". I had hoped using the `clone` method would avoid that problem. How do I get past the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`str::trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) just produces a slice, not another `String`, so when you call `clone` on it, you're calling `&str`'s implementation of `Clone`, which just copies the `&str` (a cheap pointer copy). Instead, you should use one of the [methods](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-convert-str-to-string/12160) to turn the `&str` into a `String`, such as `to_string`, `to_owned` or more verbosely, `String::from`.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut line_set = HashSet::new();

    for i in 1..4 {
        let mut line = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut line)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        line_set.insert(line.trim().to_owned());
        if i == 3 {
            for l in &line_set {
                println!("{}", l);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f42e70c582db0640690524a3d61515f5)

Comment: Thanks. So the `&str` implementation of `clone` returns a `&str`. Is there a purpose to such a call - perhaps it's useful to have it there for generic code?